# why practical byzantine faul tolerant algorithm is said to be asynchronous?

Tags: algorithm, distributed, fault-tolerance, consensus

In the PBFT paper the authors say that "The algorithm does not rely on synchrony to provide safety. Therefore, it must rely on synchrony to provide liveness [...] We guarantee liveness, i.e., clients
eventually receive replies to their requests, provided at most *(n-1)/3* replicas are faulty and *delay(t)* does not grow faster than *t* indefinitely. Here, *delay(t)* is the time between the moment when a message is sent for the first time and *t* the moment when it is received by its destination (assuming the sender keeps retransmitting the message until it is received)."
First of all, what does "The algorithm does not rely on synchrony to provide safety" mean? Moreover, it is cler that the algorithm does rely on a weak synchrony assumption to provide liveness, but the explanation results confusing to me. Is anyone able to explain it with simpler words?

In other words, as it has been proved that there not exixts any deterministic algorithm that solves consensus in asynchronous systems, where non-determinism lies in PBFT? or rather, what are the synchrony assumptions the authors introduce for the PBFT to work?

Comment: Synchrony usually means global clock. Explanation are certainly not easy to give here. There is another paper on the subject that may helps you https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01178651/document

Comment: thanks for the interesting paper, however it does not give me the answer. I can reformulate my question as follows: as it has been proved that there not exixts any deterministic algorithm that solves consensus in asynchronous systems, where non-determinism lies in PBFT?